# How to setup collisions correctly in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, collision-detection, scenekit, arkit

I'm facing a problem with collision detection.

## Current setup

1) I extended `ViewController` class with `SCNPhysicsContactDelegate`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate
```

2) I setup an OptionSet to manage collision categories:

```
// Collisions
struct CollisionCategory: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int

    static let CoinsCategory = CollisionCategory(rawValue: 0)        // Coin SCNNode
    static let CarCategory = CollisionCategory(rawValue : 1)         // Car SCNNode
    static let FinishLineCategory = CollisionCategory(rawValue: 2)   // FinishLine SCNNode
}
```

3) I setup `categoryBitMask`, `contactTestBitMask` and `collisionBitMask` of all of them:

```
// Setup car
carNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategory.CarCategory.rawValue
carNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionCategory.CoinsCategory.rawValue | CollisionCategory.FinishLineCategory.rawValue
carNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionCategory.CoinsCategory.rawValue | CollisionCategory.FinishLineCategory.rawValue

// Setup finishLine
planeNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategory.FinishLineCategory.rawValue
planeNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionCategory.CarCategory.rawValue
planeNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionCategory.CarCategory.rawValue

// Setup coin
coin.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategory.CoinsCategory.rawValue
coin.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionCategory.CarCategory.rawValue
coin.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionCategory.CarCategory.rawValue
```

4) I setup `physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact)` to manage collision when they happen:

```
func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
    if(contact.penetrationDistance >= 0.08 && contact.nodeB.name!.contains("Coin")) {
        // Remove coin from parent
        contact.nodeB.removeFromParentNode()
        // Increment counter
        self.coinsCounter += 1
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Increase coin counter
            let view = self.arSceneView.viewWithTag(10) as! UILabel
            view.text = String(self.coinsCounter)
        }
    }

    // PROBLEMS HERE
    if(contact.penetrationDistance >= 0.076 && contact.nodeB.name!.contains("FinishLine") && !self.startFinishLineCollision && !self.outOfTrack) {
        self.startFinishLineCollision = true

        // Increment lap
        if(seconds > 10) {
            self.laps += 1
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                (self.arSceneView.viewWithTag(14) as! UILabel).text = String(self.laps)
            }

            if(self.laps == 4){
                endGame()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Problem

I need to check when car touches finish line to mark a lap and increment the lap counter by 1. The problem is that I'm getting continuously contact messages from this function between `nodeA` and `nodeB`, even if there is no collision between car and finish line.

For example, in the following image there is a collision message, but there isn't an effective collision between car and finish line.

[image: collision]

What is wrong with the current setup?

## What I need

I need to check if there is a collision between car and finishline with precision.

Thank you

---

## Update

I tried the following setup too, with no solution...

```
let CoinsCategory = 2
let CarCategory = 4
let FinishLineCategory = 6

carNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CarCategory
carNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CoinsCategory | FinishLineCategory

planeNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = FinishLineCategory
planeNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CarCategory

coin.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CoinsCategory
coin.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CarCategory

func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
    switch contact.nodeB.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask {
        case FinishLineCategory:
            print("Finish Line Collision")
        case CoinsCategory:
            print("Coin Collision")
        default:
            print("Other collision")
    }
}
```

No prints are called... It's like there is no collision between objects.

**NOTE:** finishline, car and coins are all children on the the same parent (the plane below them). Is it relevant?

Comment: Should not your `FinishLineCategory` be 8 instead of 6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a workaround to workaround my issue:

1) I used a coin (yellow cube) as collider.

2) I setup it with `Color.clear` (transparent color) in such a way as to make it invisible.

3) I placed it the center of the finish line.

4) Since `contactTest` is not working, I used `penetrationDistance`:

```
func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
    if(contact.penetrationDistance >= 0.08 && contact.nodeB.name! == "Coin") {
        // Remove coin from parent
        contact.nodeB.removeFromParentNode()
        // Increment counter
        self.coinsCounter += 1
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Increase coin counter
            let view = self.arSceneView.viewWithTag(10) as! UILabel
            view.text = String(self.coinsCounter)
        }
    }



    // >>>>> NEW CODE HERE! <<<<<
    if(contact.penetrationDistance > 0.078 && contact.nodeB.name! == "CoinFinishLine" && !self.outOfTrack && !self.lapIncrement) {

        self.lapIncrement = true

        // Start lap increment timer (5 seconds)
        self.startNSecondsTimer(howMuchTime: 1.0, target: 1)

        // Increment lap
        if(seconds > 10) {
            self.laps += 1
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                (self.arSceneView.viewWithTag(14) as! UILabel).text = String(self.laps)
            }

            if(self.laps == 3){
                endGame()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyhow, if someone can explain me why I can't get `contactTestBitMask` to work and I can use only `collisionBitMask` with this solution is welcome. Thank you